# php active-record update relationships via mass assignment?

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

Does anyone know of a workaround within php-activerecord to allow object relationships to update via mass assignment?

Loaded object

```
$obj = Model::find(array(
                   'conditions'=>array('id=?', $id), 
                   'include'=>array('Relationship_one', 'relationship_two')
                   ));
```

the code

```
$obj->update_attributes(--post data--);
```

Will update object fine, but not its releationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much of an answer, but I've fixed this problem by making a function that is called with post data that

- Does some sanity checks on the post data because we can (apart from model sanity checks, just to be able to give more precise errors)
- Sets appropriate fields in this model
- Calls its sister-function in the models relationships.

The advantage you have is that you can create these relationsships too! If a relationship doesn't exist (example: the first time you add something in a one to many relationship), you can update the 'base' model, but cannot *update* the association: you need to create one first. You can check for that in your models function, and then call the relation-model's function to finish the job.

Comment: Great answer, I dunno why I didn't think of something similar.

Comment: Be aware that if create a model (relation) that has it's ID in your origional table, you need to save it first! Otherwise it obviously doesn't have an ID. This means you need to create (in some cases) the relationship first, and then you can save the id in the main table, whereas for relations that work differently (e.g. the id of your 'main' model is present in the relations' model) it might be the other way around.

Comment: Yeah this is more or less what im currently doing, which is more or less what im trying to workaround.